# How can I include a code snippet in header of certain pages?

Tags: php, opencart

In OpenCart, the  section is generated via header.tpl

How can I include a code snippet (such as Facebook conversion tracking code) only in the checkout/success page's header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `common/home` in the next example with the correct route:

```php
if ((isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home')) { 
    $this->document->addScript('javascript/facebook_tracking_code.js');
}
```

Or do it inline (in a template):

```html
<?php if ((isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home')) { ?>
<script src="javascript/facebook_tracking_code.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So, I should, in fact place the FB tracking code in a separate JS file?

Comment: Generally, it's good practice to seperate your re-used assets out to a file (js,css), but I've updated my answer with another example on how you could use the script tag.